# is BelledonneCommunications linphone is totaly free?

Tags: android, ios, sip

i want a SIP dialer a got LinPhone, that free as i know, the source code in available on GIT.

My question is that is there any money i have to pay ?

Because some io get some thing free with source code but had a hidden thing that disturbs at earlier stage, so is Lin Phone app for all platforms (Windows Phone, android & iphone) is free ?

Comment: Why don't you ask the author?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this is the Linphone you are talking about](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/downloads), their downloads page states:

> Linphone is dual licensed. It can be licensed and distributed:
>
> - under GNU GPLv2 license - for free (open source).
> - under proprietary and commercial license to be used in closed source
>     applications. Contact Belledonne Communications for costs and other
>     service information.

So, it can be freely used if your code will be open sourced according to the terms of the [GPLv2 license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html), otherwise you will need to look into getting a commercial license from them.